# what is a correct comma float regex in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I want to write a Regex that describes such inputs:

1,26m 100cm ... (with a comma, not a point)

I tried this `'^[0-9]*(\,)?[[:space:]]?([dDcCkKhHmMnNµ]m|m|dam)[0-9]*$'` but it only returns non float inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you forgot the digits after the comma.

```
^\d*(\,)?[[:space:]]?(\d*)?([dDcCkKhHmMnNµ]m|m|dam)\d*$
```